# Word Interop FindAndReplace Function replacing placeholder with image

Tags: c#, interop

I am successfully using the Word.Interop namespace to open a word document and replacing placeholder text with other text blocks. Now I would like to replace the placeholder with an image that I have stored in a image table on a database. Actually, I can copy the image into the word file, however it just places the image on top of the word document but it does not replace the placeholder.

This works when I want to replace text with text but not text to image

```
private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application wordApp, object ToFindText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            object matchCase = true;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundLike = false;
            object nmatchAllforms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiactitics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;

            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike, ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
                ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
        }
```

ChatGpt gave me a solution with Word.InlineShapes but it does not work. It does not throw any exceptions however the placeholder is not replaced.

```
private void FindAndReplace(Word.Document document, string toFindText, Word.InlineShape replaceWithImage)
{
    Word.Find find = document.Application.Selection.Find;
    find.ClearFormatting();
    find.Text = toFindText;

    while (find.Execute())
    {
        // Clear the found text
        document.Application.Selection.Text = string.Empty;

        // Add the replacement image
        Word.InlineShape newInlineShape = document.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
            replaceWithImage.Range.InlineShapes[1].Range.InlineShapes[1].LinkFormat.SourceFullName,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    }
}
```

Comment: _ChatGpt gave me a solution with Word.InlineShapes but it does not work_: Have you referred to the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia) documentation?

Comment: It seems that a simple foreach loop through Word.Range range in Wordfile.StoryRanges which searches for the placeholder can do the job. I do not know why I have to use the much more complex FindAndReplace Method I have used before. Can someone explain the difference?